# This Handler class should be static or leaks may occur (null)

Tags: android, handler

```
This Handler class should be static or leaks may occur (null)
```

Is the 'class' this message referring to 'MyActivity' here, since Handler is an object and i did declare it static. Should I ignore it or there something I should add, like 'static' somewhere in the 'MyActivity' declaration (I tried this and got errors). I notice 'WeakReference' is often suggested for this lint warning.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
...
static Handler handler;
...
handler = new Handler()
  {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
```

Comment: No, if you instantiate an inner handler class you should make the class itself static to avoid leaks. Right now you are utilizing the default class constructor which isn't static, you can make your own inner class that extends handler and is static to fix the warning.

Comment: there is a risk of "leaks (that) may occur" only if you are using any kind of "delayed" execution and you are not emptying the message queue at the end

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> since Handler is an object and i did declare it static

You declared the *data member* to be static. However, you are using anonymous inner class, and therefore your subclass of `Handler` is not `static`.

Instead of:

```
  handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // do cool stuff
    }
  };
```

use:

```
handler=new MyVeryOwnHandler();
```

where `MyVeryOwnHandler` is either a regular Java class or a `static` inner class:

```
private static class MyVeryOwnHandler extends Handler {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // do cool stuff
  }
};
```

Note that the error is that the *class* needs to be `static`; it does not say that the *object* needs to be `static`.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation of the error in this case and the example of what I should do. I find one elegant example is worth a thousand words. I got 'Modifier static not allowed here' when trying to add 'private' or 'static', but just using 'class MyVeryOwnHandler extends Handler' worked and got rid of the leaks warning.

Comment: @michael: If `MyVeryOwnHandler` is its own top-level Java class, in a `MyVeryOwnHandler.java` file, you would not need (or be allowed to use) `private` or `static`. If, however, `MyVeryOwnHandler` is an inner class of `MyActivity`, then `private` and `static` become relevant.

Comment: It does not allow me to use 'static' or 'private' when declaring MyHandler in the onCreate of my main activity, although just creating the new class without 'private' or 'static' does eliminate the error warning. I found an interesting article on this here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html, although their solution was more complicated. Declaring the class outside of onCreate is inconvenient as my handler deals with adview, inappPurchasing, interstitial ads, leaderboards, etc. who have to be redeclared static and some methods aren't recognized.

Comment: @michael: "It does not allow me to use 'static' or 'private' when declaring MyHandler in the onCreate of my main activity" -- that is because `MyVeryOwnHandler`, from my answer, is not defined in `onCreate()`. It is *instantiated* in `onCreate()`. However, it is *defined* outside of any method of the activity, as that is how you define static and inner classes in Java.

Comment: True, thanks. I'm hoping defining the new class it in onCreate, which I pretty much have to do for all the things it handles, and using 'static private Handler handler' declaring the  handler will improve it, although from what I've read it could still leak. I don't use delayed actions or large multiple messaging anyway. I may have to try Julianemailde's new answer below to keep the handler class in onCreate.

Comment: @michael: "using 'static private Handler handler'" -- no, that makes things worse. Here, a `static` `Handler` refers to the *class* being either a regular Java class or a `static` inner class.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid leaks I also migrated to a static nested class. The explanation from Android Studio says this, it might help:

> Since this Handler is declared as an inner class, it may prevent the
>   outer class from being garbage collected. **If the Handler is using a
>   Looper or MessageQueue for a thread other than the main thread, then
>   there is no issue.** If the Handler is using the Looper or MessageQueue
>   of the main thread, you need to fix your Handler declaration, as
>   follows: Declare the Handler as a static class; In the outer class,
>   instantiate a WeakReference to the outer class and pass this object to
>   your Handler when you instantiate the Handler; Make all references to
>   members of the outer class using the WeakReference object.

Before migration I used the implementation of a Looper thread as suggested by [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) , which in the end lead to the warning. *scratch

```
  class LooperThread extends Thread {
  public Handler mHandler;

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }  
 }
```